# Sonatype Nexus Support for NuGet packages with Semantic Versioning

Tags: nuget, nexus, sonatype

I am trying to use semantic versioning with the new 'Class Library (Package)' project types using the `.xproj` file extension. The version numbers look like this:

> 1.0.0-54

Is this supported in Sonatype Nexus? I am currently getting this error when I try to do a `nuget push` to the Sonatype Nexus repository:

> '1.0.0-54' is not a valid version string.

It should be noted that semantic versioning is a requirement for using these new project types and appending a build number to the end of the version number as outlined [here](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/3174).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is coming from nuget, not nexus.  The pre-release string (the part after the dash) needs to start with a-z.

See [here](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet2/blob/861741bd780225a542c73a1d0904dd33b33a7a3d/src/Core/SemanticVersion.cs#L18).